# hide single child view item based on click in expandable list

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I have expendable view list view in that I have one child view . in child view I have delete button on this delete button i want to change layout of child .

> I want hide layout on click of delete button and  show/replace different layout see child view XML its working but applied all child view and replacing all child of all group.

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res  /android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inboxChild"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/light_blue"
        android:text="Tb " />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/light_blue"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@color/dark_blue"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_vol_type_tv_dark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Open"

            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/dark_blue"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_vol_type_tv_dark"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/dark_blue"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_vol_type_tv_dark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Flage"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/deleteLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/light_blue"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/dark_blue"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_vol_type_tv_dark"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/dark_blue"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_vol_type_tv_dark"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Flage"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

//see child view adapter

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
    boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_child, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inboxChild);
        final LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        final LinearLayout deleteLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteLayout);


        mainLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        deleteLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        Button delete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                deleteLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mainLayout. setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Try `notifyDataSetChanged();` after setVisibility ...

Comment: it is not recycler view

Comment: it is changing all child i want  based on goup position if i click on delete only those child should chnge not all child

Comment: Have you check code by debugging that cursor goes over there?

Comment: ya this code is working

Comment: but when i m expanding one group item all group layout changing

Comment: You are right because they are using same view for next Item. Let me check if I can help you.

Comment: ok bro thank for helping

Comment: Did you get idea?

Comment: based on group position i want to hide

Comment: Then there is one possible way, but it's awkward. Like, get the position of child and parent in one-list when you click on button. then notifyDataSetChanged() and check and set visibility of child whether it is in  new stored list.